# Quotient space, a fundamental group, and higher homotopy groups 2

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups, homotopy-theory, smooth-manifolds

Previously, I ask for comments/suggestions on setting up the calculation in [Quotient space, homogeneous space, and higher homotopy groups](https://mathoverflow.net/q/309566/27004). There, however, I was looking for whatever methods and tools you recommend.

Being more down to earth now, I had decided to do the explicit calculation simply based on the exact sequence and see whatever clues I can find. I like to present my results and see whether this leads to a complete answer.

The goal is the same. But since this new post contains more information than the previous ones, I believe that these will be useful to post as a sequel question suitable for other people who are interested in this too.

Question:
For this precise quotient space 
$
G/H,
$ (Can we think it of as some more familiar manifold?)

> - What is the homotopy group?
>     $$
>   \pi_j(G/H)=?
>   $$
>     for $j=1,2,3,4,5,6$.

Here we still take

> $${G}=\frac{SU(N)_A \times SU(N)_{B_1} \times SU(N)_{B_2} \times U(1)}{(\mathbb{Z}_N)^2}\equiv \frac{G_0}{G_1},$$
>   $$=\frac{PSU(N)_A \times SU(N)_{B_1} \times SU(N)_{B_2}}{(\mathbb{Z}_N)}\equiv \frac{G_0'}{G_1'}
> $$
>   and the subgroup $H$ of the $G$ as:
>   $$H=\frac{SU(N)_{A,B}}{\mathbb{Z}_N}\times \mathbb{Z}_2=PSU(N)_{A,B} \times  \mathbb{Z}_2.$$
>   Note $H$ is not a normal subgroup of $G$. So generally $G/H$ is not a nice Lie group but just a quotient space. $SU(N)$ is the special unitary group written in terms of rank-$N$ matrix, and $PSU(N)$ is the projective special unitary group written in terms of rank-$N$ matrix. See more details [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/309566/27004). The $\mathbb{Z}_N \equiv \mathbb{Z}/(N\mathbb{Z})$ is a cyclcic elementary abelian group of order $N$.
>
> Here $N$ is an integer, we can take $N=3$ an odd integer throughout this post.

I like to determine the homotopy groups from the long
exact sequence
$$
...
\to \pi_n(H)     \to \pi_n(G)     \to \pi_n(G/H)
\to \pi_{n-1}(H) \to \pi_{n-1}(G) \to \pi_{n-1}(G/H) \to ....
\tag{(!!)}
$$

So I start from computing the homotopy group of $H$:
We can see that
$$\pi_{0}(H)=\pi_{0}(\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2,$$
$$\pi_{1}(H)=\pi_{1}(PSU(N))=\mathbb{Z}_N,$$
$$\pi_{2}(H)=\pi_{2}(PSU(N))=0,$$
$$\pi_{3}(H)=\pi_{3}(PSU(N))=\mathbb{Z},$$
$$\pi_{4}(H)=\pi_{4}(PSU(N))=0,$$
$$\pi_{5}(H)=\pi_{5}(PSU(N))=\mathbb{Z},$$
$$\pi_{6}(H)=\pi_{6}(PSU(N))=\mathbb{Z}_6, \text{ if } N=3$$

Then I compute the homotopy group of $G$:
We can see that
$$\pi_{0}(G)=0,$$
$$\pi_{1}(G)=\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_N,$$
Here $\pi_{1}(G)$ is related to [the comment here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/309781/27004) given by @YCor and @Dan Ramras, who says that "the fundamental group is isomorphic to the preimage $\tilde{G}_1$ of $G_1$ in the universal covering of $G_0$." I have another way to look at it, and I agree that $\pi_{1}(G)=\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_N$ seems correct (Further criticism is welcome?).

$$\pi_{2}(G)=\pi_{2}(PSU(N)_A \times SU(N)_{B_1} \times SU(N)_{B_2})=0,$$
$$\pi_{3}(G)=\pi_{3}(PSU(N)_A \times SU(N)_{B_1} \times SU(N)_{B_2})=\mathbb{Z}^3,$$
$$\pi_{4}(G)=\pi_{4}(PSU(N)_A \times SU(N)_{B_1} \times SU(N)_{B_2})=0,$$
$$\pi_{5}(G)=\pi_{5}(PSU(N)_A \times SU(N)_{B_1} \times SU(N)_{B_2})=\mathbb{Z}^3,$$
$$\pi_{6}(G)=\pi_{6}(PSU(N)_A \times SU(N)_{B_1} \times SU(N)_{B_2})=\mathbb{Z}_6^3, \text{ if } N=3$$

By the method in Eq.(!!), we can find that:
$$
\pi_2(G/H)=0
\to \pi_1(H)=\mathbb{Z}_N      \to \pi_1(G)=\mathbb{Z} \times  \mathbb{Z}_N    \to \pi_1(G/H)
\to \pi_{0}(H)=\mathbb{Z}_2 \to \pi_{0}(G)=0 \to \pi_{0}(G/H)=0, \tag{(a-1)}
$$
so
$$
0
\to \mathbb{Z}_N      \to \mathbb{Z} \times  \mathbb{Z}_N    \to \pi_1(G/H)
\to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to 0 \to 0,
\tag{(a-2)}
$$
Notice Eq.(a-2) boils down to 
$$
0
\to 0     \to \mathbb{Z}     \to \pi_1(G/H)
\to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to 0 \to 0,
\tag{(a-3)},
$$
Eq.(a-3) is related to classified the $H^2(B\mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{Z})$. There are 3 choices, $\pi_1(G/H)=\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_2, \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}\rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2$. These 3 cases are mentioned in a nice post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040450/extensions-of-mathbbz-by-mathbbz-2. I don't have a definite way to determine the unique answer, so this I require whatever advice you suggested.

Then we also have
$$
\pi_7(G/H)=0 \to \pi_6(H)=\mathbb{Z}_6      \to \pi_6(G)=\mathbb{Z}_6^3    \to 
\pi_6(G/H)$$ 
$$\to \pi_5(H)=\mathbb{Z}      \to \pi_5(G)=\mathbb{Z}^3    \to \pi_5(G/H)
\to \pi_{4}(H)=0 \to \pi_{4}(G)=0 \to$$
$$
\pi_4(G/H)=0
\to \pi_3(H)=\mathbb{Z}      \to \pi_3(G)=\mathbb{Z}^3    \to \pi_3(G/H)
\to \pi_{2}(H)=0 \to \pi_{2}(G)=0 \to \pi_{2}(G/H)=0, \tag{(b-1)}
$$
We can determine $\pi_3(G/H)$, $\pi_5(G/H)$ and $\pi_6(G/H)$ from
$$
0
\to \mathbb{Z}      \to \mathbb{Z}^3    \to \pi_3(G/H)
\to 0  \tag{(b-2)}
$$
$$
0 \to \mathbb{Z}_6      \to \mathbb{Z}_6^3    \to 
\pi_6(G/H)
\to \mathbb{Z}      \to \mathbb{Z}^3    \to \pi_5(G/H)
\to 0  \tag{(b-3)}
$$

> My claim/tentative answer is that:
>   $$
> \pi_{0}(G/H)=0
> $$
>   $$
> \pi_{1}(G/H)=\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_2 (?)
> $$
>   $$
> \pi_{2}(G/H)=0
> $$
>   $$
> \pi_{3}(G/H)=\mathbb{Z}^2
> $$
>   $$
> \pi_{4}(G/H)=0
> $$
>   $$
> \pi_{5}(G/H)=\mathbb{Z}^2 (?)
> $$
>   $$
> \pi_{6}(G/H)=\mathbb{Z}_6^2 (?)
> $$

In particular, I am now so sure $\pi_{5}(G/H)$ and $\pi_{6}(G/H)$, am I too innocent about my answers?

P.S. If you are not familiar with the homotopy groups of unitary Lie group, you can find the info [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2454985/79069).

Comment: Stare at the group and you see that it is a connected one.